# Different methods of denying access in httaccess

Tags: .htaccess, deny

I want to deny the access to all files and subdirectories in a given folder via .htaccess.
I found this two methods:

```
deny from all
```

```
<Files "*">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Is there any difference between this two?

Comment: Both ways will not work with apache2 as of version 2.4. Rather use the new `Require` directive ([see manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html))

Comment: @digijay It still "works" on Apache 2.4, but is _deprecated_. It is intended to be used for _backwards compatibility_ only.

Comment: @MrWhite And only with the use of mod_access_compat, to discourage its use and keep people from accidentally still using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, the `Deny` and `Order` directives are formerly deprecated on Apache 2.4 (which I would assume you are using - see below). And are intended for backwards compatibility only (mod_access_compat). These should only be used on **Apache 2.2** and earlier.

> ```
> deny from all
> ```

Yes, this does "deny" all access to the current directory, files and subdirectories. However, without explicitly stating the `Order` in which the `Deny` and `Allow` directives are processed then how it interacts with related directives is not clearly defined.

`Allow` directives in a subdirectory `.htaccess` file should override this.

> ```
> <Files "*">
>     Order Deny,Allow
>     Deny from all
> </Files>
> ```

By wrapping the directives in a `<Files>` container you are forcing the block to be merged *late*. This has the effect of potentially overriding `Allow` directives in a subdirectory, unlike the example above. Unless the `Allow` directives in a subdirectory are also enclosed in a `<Files>` container. This may or may not be desirable. In most cases this is not required.

The `*` is simply a wildcard that matches all files (and directories).

On **Apache 2.4** you should use the `Require` directive (mod_authz_core) instead:

```
Require all denied
```

The same regarding the `<Files "*">` container would apply here also.